# Django admin inlines to parent model

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have several related models. In django admin I want to create `Appeal`.

As can be seen from the models, I need to select from the `Assignment` list, but in my case, most often, it needs to be created from scratch. Django admin provides this option if I click on "+"

Then, inside the `Assigment`, I need to select `ClientProfile`, but again, in most cases, I need to create it again, which means I'll click on the "+"

But as can be seen from my models, ClientProfile refers to User, and more often, it also needs to be created anew, and so again press on "+"

And the most terrible thing in this situation is that User refers to the model of Address.

The question is, is it possible to do something so that you do not have to press 3-5 times to "+"? Each press is accompanied by the opening pop, and it's not very convenient.

I'm thinking about the inheritance of forms or models themselves, creating several abstract models, I also thought about [WizardView](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html), which I could not integrate into Django-admin.

I'm confused and do not understand how to do it right.

The problem is that I built the model architecture incorrectly?
I would not say that this is so, I like how the models are related.

```
class Appeal(Base):
   ...
   assigment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, null=True)
   ...


class Assignment(Base):
    ...
    client = models.ForeignKey(ClientProfile, null=True)
    ...
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, null=True)
    ...


class ClientProfile(Base):
    ...
    user = AutoOneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True)
    ...


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    phone_number = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneNumber)
    ...
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, null=True)
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Its possible to add inlines to related models in Django admin as can be read from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/). But Django admin is not always reliable, hence to meet your requirements its better to have your own designed admin panel.

Comment: I certainly know about Inlines. But I need the opposite.I need to add parents to children. In the example that I indicated to create an entry in the first table, I need to click on 5 pluses, and fill in 5 forms.
I want to minimize this, whether through override forms, or SessionView in WizzardForms